# Why does Google Chrome replace "fl" with blocks on all PDFs it shows, but Adobe Reader works fine?

Tags: pdf, google-chrome, encoding, internationalization

When I open PDFs in Chrome that contain words like "files", the "fi" is replaced by a square block. Opening the same PDF in Adobe Reader or Preview works fine.  Anyway to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug with Chrome's PDF Viewer, which is fixed in Chrome Milestone 25: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=80996